# Showing that $\mathrm{div}_{\mu}X=\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^i}$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry, derivatives

Let $\mu$ be a non-vanishing $1$-form on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Given a smooth vector field X on $\mathbb{R}^n$, we define the divergence of $X$ wrt $\mu$, denoted by $\mathrm{div}_{\mu}X$, by

$L_X \mu = (\mathrm{div}_{\mu}X)\mu$

where $L_X$ is the usual Lie derivative. Let $\Phi_t$ denote the flow of $X$.

For $\mu = dx^1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx^n$ show that $\displaystyle \mathrm{div}_{\mu}X=\frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^i}$.

I started by using Cartan's magic formula so that

$L_X \mu = di_X\mu+i_Xd\mu$ but $d\mu=d(dx^1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx^n)=d^2x^1\wedge dx^2 \wedge \dots \wedge dx^n=0$ so we have that

$L_X \mu=d i_X\mu = di_X(dx^1 \wedge \dots \wedge dx^n)$ but I am not sure where to go from here. It seems to be a problem that the vector field is still an arbitrary/general one.

Comment: Possible link to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1077839/show-that-phi-t-mu-mu-iff-mathrmdiv-mux-0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the clue is in the question itself. We must write
$$X = \sum X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i},$$
so now explicitly compute $\iota_X\mu$ and you're one step away.

In the explicit case of a vector field on $\Bbb R^n$, we're just writing $X = \sum X^ie_i$, where $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors on $\Bbb R^n$. So what you need to think about is this: What is $\displaystyle \iota_X dx^1\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$ when $X=e_i$? Start with $i=1$. You should get $dx^2\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$. To do general $i$, you would like to write $dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge\dots\wedge dx^n$ as $(-1)^? dx^i\wedge dx^1\wedge dx^2\wedge \dots \wedge\widehat{dx^i}\wedge\dots \wedge dx^n$. It will help to write out several concrete examples. Then remember the linearity properties of $\iota_X$.

Comment: Where does $X = \sum X^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ come from? I have not seen it before and therefore am unable to explicitly compute $i_X \mu$.

Comment: It's the standard expression for the vector field $X$ in the local coordinate system $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$. It no doubt appeared earlier in your exposition.

Comment: Unfortunately it has not featured. The only definition I have of a vector field is: Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, U open. A vector field is a map, $\mathbb{X}: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n; x \mapsto \mathbb{X}(x)=(\mathbb{X}^1(x),\dots,\mathbb{X}^n(x))$. Could you point me to somewhere where I can see the basic of the expression you used?

Comment: Oh, I see the problem. A vector field on $U\subset\Bbb R^n$ is, as you said, given by a vector-valued function with components $(X^1,\dots,X^n)$. These are the same $X^i$ to which I referred. My notation $\partial/\partial x^i$ holds more generally on manifolds but, in particular, with the standard coordinate system $(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ on $\Bbb R^n$, $\partial/\partial x^i$ *is* just the $i$th standard basis vector.

Comment: I would have thought that $e_{k}=(0,\dots,1,\dots,0)$ with a one in the k'th position would have been the basis vector. How are the two related?

Comment: Right, @1234. These agree :) The general notation comes from thinking of vector fields as directional derivative operators. So the directional derivative in the direction of $e_k$ *is* given just by taking the partial derivative with respect to $x^k$.

Comment: Are we summing over the $i$'s in $\displaystyle \frac{\partial X^i}{\partial x^i}$ then?

Comment: Yes, that's the "Einstein summation convention," which I always avoid. I write the sum sign :)

Comment: I think you might be missing the $\mathbb{X}^i$'s in your solution

Comment: On purpose. I told you to use linearity of $\iota_X$ :)